# EasyNetQ/RabbitMQ client not getting response in IIS Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm using EasyNetQ/RabbitMQ to connect a web application running in IIS to a Windows service. However, I don't seem to get the request/response to work. I pretty sure it's not a code problem but I'm running out of ideas where to look at next.

This is a test console application that works just perfectly:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var stopHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        var producer = new Thread(() =>
        {
            string cs = "host=localhost;virtualHost=/;username=demo;password=y4xHEyq3nQOd;timeout=120;persistentMessages=false;prefetchcount=1";
            var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(cs, x => x.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(s => new EasyNetQ.Loggers.ConsoleLogger()));

            while (!stopHandle.IsSet)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = bus.Request<AutomationRequest, AutomationResponse>(new AutomationRequest
                    {
                        taskId = "140061381555",
                        arguments = "type=pdf",
                        issueId = 97630548355,
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.status + ", " + result.status + ", " + result.downloadUrl);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                }
                if (!stopHandle.IsSet) Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            bus.Dispose();
        });

        producer.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        stopHandle.Set();
        producer.Join();
    }
}
```

This on the other hand is the same test code but as a web application:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = "host=localhost;virtualHost=/;username=demo;password=y4xHEyq3nQOd;timeout=120;persistentMessages=false;prefetchcount=1";
            IBus bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(cs, x => x.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(s => new EasyNetQ.Loggers.ConsoleLogger()));

            try
            {
                var result = bus.Request<AutomationRequest, AutomationResponse>(new AutomationRequest
                {
                    taskId = "140061381555",
                    arguments = "type=pdf",
                    issueId = 97630548355,
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.status + ", " + result.status + ", " + result.downloadUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
            }
            bus.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Web application sends the message just fine, at queued and it's processed on the back end. Back-end provides the response with the correct correlationID and queues it. However, for some reason unknown to me, the Web application never gets the response.

The Web application eventually gets a timeout. However, the length of the timeout is not the problems, as the getting the response into the queue takes just about two seconds, and changing the timeout to two minutes on both sides does not make any difference.

Does somebody have a ready solution what to fix? Or any ideas where to look? I have googled everything I could figure out about EasyNetQ or RabbitMQ but I didn't even find anybody having reported about similar problems.

--karri

Comment: I've similar problem. Did you found any solution?